# Keep the MySQL Version Up to Date

Tags: mysql

1. How to restrict where the MySQL listens
2. Disable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
3. Remove content of MySQL History File
4. Add application specific users
5. Restrict access to the MySQL data Directory to only the server account
6. Do not run MySQL as root...create other  accounts with limited privileges for 
   day to day use
7. Keep the MySQL Version Up to Date

Comment: Look like you have to read official documentation first.

Comment: Was there a question?

Answer (score -1):

1. GRANT ... TO user@'1.2.3.4' ...
2. local_infile = OFF
3. "history" file?  To what are you referring?
4. GRANT ... ON app1.* TO user1@...
5. Run on Unix, where, by default, the directory is owned by "mysql".
6. GRANT...
7. Depends on the OS.